# How to running function speed up

Tags: google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets

Google spreadsheet app script - how to Running function speed up [ with this code ]

I want to make it faster then now

I made some script to make many copied sheets about 366.
But, google spreadsheet has limt time to running function.
so I have to waiting and running second function.

copy and sheetname changing code.
sheetnames are January 1 to December 31 and include February 29
like[01.01][01.02][01.03]....[02.29]...[12.30][12.31]

I'm waiting for some cleaver solution
thank you for leading

```
function Sheets_Copying_with_Name(){
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0]; 
 var Typing_Month =1;
 var Typing_Day=1;
 var MAX_Day = 31; 

  for (Typing_Month; Typing_Month< 13; Typing_Month++)
  {
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet ADDRESS");   
    if ((Typing_Month==1)||(Typing_Month==3)||(Typing_Month==5)||(Typing_Month==7)||(Typing_Month==8)||(Typing_Month==10)||(Typing_Month==12))  { MAX_Day=31; }
    if ((Typing_Month==4)||(Typing_Month==6)||(Typing_Month==9)||(Typing_Month==11)) { MAX_Day=30; }
    if ( Typing_Month==2) { MAX_Day=29;}
    for( Typing_Day; Typing_Day < MAX_Day +1; Typing_Day++ )
    { if( (Typing_Month < 10) && (Typing_Day < 10)) {  sheet.copyTo(destination).setName("0"+Typing_Month+".0"+Typing_Day);}
      if( (Typing_Month < 10) && (Typing_Day > 9)) {  sheet.copyTo(destination).setName("0"+Typing_Month+"."+Typing_Day);}
      if( (Typing_Month > 9) && (Typing_Day < 10)) { sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(Typing_Month+".0"+Typing_Day);}
      if( (Typing_Month > 9) && (Typing_Day > 9)) {  sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(Typing_Month+"."+Typing_Day);}
    }
Typing_Day = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- Your script works fine. But you want to reduce the process cost of the script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

In your script, the sheet is copied in the for loop. The number of loop seems about 360. And in this case, the process cost will be high. So in this answer, in order to reduce the cost of the script, I would like to propose the following flow using Sheets API.

1. Copy the source sheet to the destination Spreadsheet.
2. Create the request body for copying the source sheet using the duplicateSheet request of Sheets API.
3. Add the request body for deleting the source sheet using the deleteSheet request of Sheets API.
4. Request to the batchUpdate method of Sheets API using the created request body.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function Sheets_Copying_with_Name(){
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the destinaton Spreadsheet ID.

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0]; 
  var Typing_Month =1;
  var Typing_Day=1;
  var MAX_Day = 31; 

  // I modified below script.
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sheet.copyTo(destination).setName("sourceSheet");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sourceSheetId = sourceSheet.getSheetId();
  var requests = [];
  for (Typing_Month; Typing_Month< 13; Typing_Month++) {
    if ((Typing_Month==1)||(Typing_Month==3)||(Typing_Month==5)||(Typing_Month==7)||(Typing_Month==8)||(Typing_Month==10)||(Typing_Month==12))  { MAX_Day=31; }
    if ((Typing_Month==4)||(Typing_Month==6)||(Typing_Month==9)||(Typing_Month==11)) { MAX_Day=30; }
    if ( Typing_Month==2) { MAX_Day=29;}
    for( Typing_Day; Typing_Day < MAX_Day +1; Typing_Day++ ) {
      if( (Typing_Month < 10) && (Typing_Day < 10)) {
        requests.push({duplicateSheet: {sourceSheetId: sourceSheetId, newSheetName: "0"+Typing_Month+".0"+Typing_Day}});
      }
      if( (Typing_Month < 10) && (Typing_Day > 9)) {
        requests.push({duplicateSheet: {sourceSheetId: sourceSheetId, newSheetName: "0"+Typing_Month+"."+Typing_Day}});
      }
      if( (Typing_Month > 9) && (Typing_Day < 10)) {
        requests.push({duplicateSheet: {sourceSheetId: sourceSheetId, newSheetName: Typing_Month+".0"+Typing_Day}});
      }
      if( (Typing_Month > 9) && (Typing_Day > 9)) {
        requests.push({duplicateSheet: {sourceSheetId: sourceSheetId, newSheetName: Typing_Month+"."+Typing_Day}});
      }
    }
    Typing_Day = 1;
  }
  requests.push({deleteSheet: {sheetId: sourceSheetId}});
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, destinationSpreadsheetId);
}
```

- When I tested this script in my environment, the process time of the script was about 30 seconds. In this case, after the script was finished, it was requried to wait for completely copying the sheets. After this, please reopen the destination Spreadsheet. By this, I could confirm that all sheets were created. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- In your script, I think that when the script is run, about 360 sheets are created in the destination Spreadsheet. In this case, please be careful the following limitation. [Ref](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)

  > ​Up to 5 million cells or 18,278 columns (column ZZZ) for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.
- If an error related to this limitation occurs, please reduce the number of cells of the source sheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [DuplicateSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#duplicatesheetrequest)
- [DeleteSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletesheetrequest)

Comment: That is remarkable solution!! appreciate your elaborate from south korea

Comment: @riore El Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.